# Class method return type to another method

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in typescript to have a return type point to another method?

```
export class _StringHandler {
    getString (s): string {
        if (s === 'red') throw new Error;
        return s; 
    }
    getStrings (s: string[]): ReturnType<this.getString>[] {
        return s.map(this.getString);
    }
}
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a type query to get the type of a method.

```
export class _StringHandler {
    getString (s): string {
        if (s === 'red') throw new Error;
        return s; 
    }
    getStrings (s: string[]): ReturnType<_StringHandler['getString']>[] {
        return s.map(this.getString);
    }
}
```